# Unable to locate implementation of logistic density distribution in NeuS (neural surface reconstruction method) paper repository

Tags: python, deep-learning, neural-network, computer-vision, 3d-reconstruction

I have been going through the [`NEUS paper repository`](https://github.com/Totoro97/NeuS) on GitHub and came across a mention of a logistic density distribution in the paper. However, I couldn't find the corresponding implementation in the code.

In the paper, it states:

[image]

I am particularly interested in understanding how this logistic density distribution is utilized within the volume rendering process. Unfortunately, I haven't been able to locate the implementation in the codebase.

I would appreciate it if someone could provide guidance on where I can find the implementation of the logistic density distribution in the code.

This is what I managed to get so far:

The equation (13) in the paper [image] shows how alpha is calculated. This matches with the 171st line of code in the file `models/renderer.py`:

```py
alpha = (prev_cdf - next_cdf + 1e-5) / (prev_cdf + 1e-5)
```

However, I could not clearly track how  `prev_cdf` and `next_cdf` include the calculation of the logistic density distribution function.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://github.com/search?q=repo%3ATotoro97%2FNeuS+%28next_cdf+OR+prev_cdf%29&type=code and then you need to see the relation between "sigmoid" and "logistic"